# LOG: unexpected EOF on client connection with an open transaction

Tags: django, postgresql, docker, django-rest-framework, celery

I am getting  `LOG:  unexpected EOF on client connection with an open transaction` from postgresql log when saving object on django admin and no any log or error from django, and browser gives me following error:
[image]

Everything was fine before I started to use Celery for schedule tasks. I couldn't find where the problem is coming.
**signals.py**

```py
@receiver(post_save, sender=Posts)
def send_save_obj(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    # Translate to latin
    relates_to = instance
    title = to_latin(instance.title)
    author = instance.author
    ...
    # Creating latin obj
    if created and language == 'uz':
        def save_latn_obj():

            # create latin post
            post = PostUzLatn.objects.create(
                relates_to=relates_to,
                title=title,
                ...
            )
            post.tags.add(tags)
        transaction.on_commit(save_latn_obj)
        
    # Sending to telegram channel
  
    # Get the current time in the server's local time zone
    server_time = datetime.now()

    # Create a timezone object for Tashkent
    tashkent_tz = pytz.timezone('Asia/Tashkent')

    # Convert the server time to Tashkent time
    tashkent_time = server_time.astimezone(tashkent_tz)

    if 'tg' in instance.social_network \
        and publish <= tashkent_time:
        send_news(
            title=instance.title, 
        )

        # Update status after sending msg
        Posts.objects.filter(id=instance.id).update(is_sent=["is_sent_tg",])

    # Delete the cache key to invalidate the cache for this view
    cache.clear()
```

**bot.py**

```py
def send_news(title):
    if tizer:
        bot.send_video(CHANNEL_ID, video=tizer, caption=title, supports_streaming=True)
    else:
        bot.send_photo(CHANNEL_ID, image, caption=title)
```

Comment: There is only `unexpected EOF on client connection with an open transaction`

Comment: Ah, that was the server message. I get it. If both client and server complain about a terminated connection, some firewall or other network component in between must have closed the connection. Misconfigured network components sometimes do that with connections that are idle for a long time.

Comment: Is there anything to cause problem like that? Because when I switched to another branch on my repo it is working fine, I just added celery and redis to my project, didn't make any major changes.

Comment: I'd use a network sniffer like Wireshark so see what is going on.